# checkbox selected addclass to a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, addclass

I'm trying to add a new class "ok" to an `<a href>` when it's checked.
I'm using bootstrap, jquery and bootstrap table from http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table.

the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/x0wegnhs/1/

Can you help me to release that ?

```
<tr>
    <td class="bs-checkbox"><input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td style="text-align: left; "><a href="#" class="file">file 1</a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `closest` to find the nearest `tr`, then `find` to find the anchor link. Use `toggleClass` with a boolean value to turn on/off that `ok` class based on the checked state.

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/x0wegnhs/6/

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td a').toggleClass('ok', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

---

**Side notes on jQuery vs direct access:**

As `@Karl-André Gagnon` points out this can, apparently, be shortened a little by going RAW JS for the checked property like this:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td a').toggleClass('ok', this.checked));
});
```

However, I would normally have had a variable for the `$(this)` element and my selector constants, so:

```
$this.is(checkedSelector)
```

becomes the following when minified:

```
t.is(c)
```

which is then actually shorter than:

```
this.checked
```

because `this` and the `checked` property cannot be minified :)

Comment: upvoted, but is it to prevent any error that you are using `.is("checked")` instead of `this.checked`?

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon: Added your suggestion (and the reason I got into that habit - smaller minified code).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to find closest tr as somebody mentioned. You must do for each loop with jquery. When you do that, you are positioned at input tag (your "this" let me say it like that is referenced to input field when you loop). So you need first go out your input tag because you can't use next() because there is no other tags except parent tags after that input tag in that hierarchy position. That's why you need to use first parent() (to get outside where you are), so you could be positioned in td parent tag. Then you use next() to go to next td tag, and then you use find("a") to find your a tag and add to it class "ok".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=btSelectItem]").each(function () {
        if (this.checked){
            $(this).parent().next().find("a").addClass("ok");
        }
    }); 
});
```

You asked for the solution of this:

> I'm trying to add a new class "ok" to an  when it's checked.

You can find it here - with piece of code I described, class will be added on any a tag next to it's checkbox. You can inspect the source and see for yourself that class ok is added to checked checkbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/upquya6p/2/